# How to generate new dynamic pages with Simple Forms (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm building a rails application and I need to be able to generate new pages from a prebuilt page (basically a bunch of similar pages all over the site that all can be edited from one page, similar to how blog apps work in Rails with the show.html.erb).

How can I do this simply?

Comment: You mean add nested fields for your associations?

Comment: This isn't "built into" rails or any other web framework (except for maybe drag-and-drop website creators like Weebly or Dreamweaver).

Comment: @PetrGazarov I started looking into that and it's similar to what I would need. You know how you can build one profile page and then all of the users information around the site is loaded into the one profile page, so if you edit that one page, everyones profile changes because it's simply grabbing an existing page then loading in data. I want to be able to do this in a subreddit kind of fashion (without it being custom for people).